# Storing and Saving Data from tables in multiple pages in different lines

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have created the following code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

records = []

for factoryId in range(3995, 4000):
    url = "http://www.modon.gov.sa/ar/IndustrialCities/Pages/factory.aspx?
    factoryId=" + str(factoryId)
    r = requests.get(url)
    content = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'ModonInfoTable'})

    for tr in results.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')[1].text
        records.append(tds)

print(records)
```

Desired Output for factoryId 3995, 3996:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6 
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6
```

My problem is trying to loop through the table, collect the comma separated values from column # 2 (left hand column), then adding newline then scraping the next record in the next page.

Currently, i append all values in a list, but can't separate by newline.

I have tried to use numpy, and to use `'\n'.join(records)` -- both can't get the desired results.

Eventually i will be exporting all values using pandas to CSV - and this can be done easily.

Only problem for now is looping through records, and storing data correctly.

Comment: @coder - Thanks for your comment - factoryId +=1 removed. 
also sample of desired output is added to the question.

Thanks

Comment: The answer is really easy even to post it, just add `records.append('\n')` outside the for loop, and then when you finish scraping `print ''.join(records)`. This should work I suppose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `records` should be a nested list with each sublist conaining the table cells, so the results from each html table would be on a new row when you write the csv file.

```
records = []
for factoryId in range(3995, 4000):
    url = "http://www.modon.gov.sa/ar/IndustrialCities/Pages/factory.aspx?factoryId=" + str(factoryId)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'ModonInfoTable'})
    records.append([tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in results.find_all('tr')])

print(records)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked just as desired. My problem was in adding each factory info in its own line.